# How to add things to an array in foreach Loop?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, foreach

I want to make an API, which puts the emails from an IMAP Server to a JSON Output. I can get the Mails and so.
I create the JSON Output with an Array:

```
$arr = array('number' => $overview->msgno, 'date' => $overview->date,);
```

So, the thing is, that I get the mails in an foreach loop.
And when I put this Line to the loop and the

```
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

outside, it only prints the last Line. If I put it in the the Loop, its just a page with even a new Bracket open and closed. I want all the outputs in order like:

```
{
"1": [
    {
        "author": "Mister X",
        "title": "Here is the title"
        "message": "Here it should print the Message"
    }]
"2": [
   {and so on}]
```

}

I tried `array_pusch($arr, $msgno, $date)`. Both variables I saved in the foreach loop but it doesnt work :(

Hope u can help me,

dunklesToast

---

CODE:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{mcggehrden.de:143}INBOX", $email, $login)
     or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$MC = imap_check($mbox);

$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);

 foreach ($result as $overview) {

    $arr = array();
    $number = $overview->msgno;
    $date = $overview->date;

    array_push($arr, $msgno, $date);

 }
 echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: SO show the code you have

Comment: You ask us to help you with your code, but you don't post your code. How do you expect us to help?

Comment: @RiggsFolly and I just added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right your issue is that you have initialized the array you want to hold all the data inside the foreach loop. So each time round the loop you destory any previous data that it held and load only the data from this iteration

Also you are being returned an object, and your JSON result example suggested you wanted an array of objects so you may as well take all the returned object and just add it to the array

```
$mbox = imap_open("{mcggehrden.de:143}INBOX", $email, $login)
     or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$MC = imap_check($mbox);

$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);

$arr = array();     
foreach ($result as $overview) {
    $arr[] = $overview;
}

 echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thats what I needed! But its not printed pretty. Its in one line :(

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` is only available in PHP5.4.0 or greater. Also remember its data, other programs dont care about PRETTY

Comment: 7.0.5 is the PhP Version and i am viewing it on GoogleChrome

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the array in each execution of the loop. To add elements you have to do something like this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($result as $overview) {
    $arr[] = array('number' => $overview->msgno, 'date' => $overview->date,);
}
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: So, thats good. But its no really pretty printed. Everthing is behind each other...

Answer (score 0):

```
$return_arr=array();
$g=mysqli_query($con,"select * from YourTableName");
while($j=mysqli_fetch_array($g,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $row_array['arr_msgno']=$j['msgno'];
    $row_array['arr_date']=$j['date'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);

}

$result['yourTableName']=$return_arr;
echo json_encode($result);
```

use like this, it will work for sure

Comment: Its not really that what I want :(